# GIT CSS Multiple branches, so many conflicts

Tags: git, version-control, github

So...

We are using this work flow called "git flow" so we create a different feature for all the different bugs....

Which seems great for the PHP guys... however when I have like 5 different features, and then I go to deploy these features for testing when I try to merge them or rebase them I get like a million conflict errors.

Obviously this is because the SASS or CSS files are changing and are different in each one. 
Just curious if anyone has any solutions to this? Or run into this issue?

Like can I put the SASS and CSS in one folder, and when I create a new branch can it pull all the latest SASS and CSS into it, and when I push that it also updates the SASS and CSS in the main folder?

I dunno sounds kinda confusing, not sure if that would work.

The only other thing I can think of is maybe just using SASS, after I finish a branch push that... go into the other branches pull the new SASS files, delete the stylesheet, re compile the SASS into CSS and then push that.

So then they always have the latest styles... However it just seems like a bit annoying to have to keep going in to a different branch and recompile.

Or is there any different workflow to not cause this issue at all??

Thanks heaps!

Comment: Is SASS supposed to be compiled down into CSS? We use LESS and compile that to CSS at my workplace, but we only check in the LESS files, not the compiled CSS (we used to be using [Git Flow](http://nvie.com/git-model/) too, it's a common Git workflow). Is there a need for you to check-in your compiled CSS?

Comment: Well kind of because, then the backend devs would have to compile the SASS - CSS when they do a git pull. 

However, in doing that, do you edit the same LESS file on multiple branches? Do you get conflicts say if you edit the same LESS file in 5 places on 5 different branches?

Comment: We don't have any "backend" devs, we're all either full-stack or frontend. Everyone compiles CSS when they get a new build. It's just like compiling any other source code (we use C#), so I don't see the issue, it's a normal routine for us. As for conflicts in the LESS files, yes, sometimes they happen, that's just a normal everyday part of our develpoment workflow.

Comment: If you keep getting a lot of conflicts when you merge or rebase, it could be a sign that you're not syncing up your feature branches with the upstream branches often enough. The team I work in syncs our feature branches with an upstream branch like master or develop ***constantly***, so we never have to resolve a bunch of conflicts at once, only a little bit at a time, if there are any conflicts to resolve at all.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I figured out how to do it is

Create a new feature

1) Checkout ONLY the SASS folder from the last edited branch (e.g. git checkout feature/sass-01 path/to/sass) - This will only pull in the SASS so you will not have any of the template files you changed

Have sass --watch sass:css running and it compile the CSS for you ready to start working on right away.

2) Add/Edit the SASS files and template files to fix the ticket

When you are ready to deploy multiple features for testing

1) Go back into their feature branches

2) Checkout SASS folder from the VERY LAST feature you worked on. Have have sass --watch sass:css running.

3) Git Commit and Git Push the SASS / CSS files.

Comment: build artifacts (in your case the compiled CSS files) should *not* be committed into your git repo, as was mentioned in the comments on your question. you should only ever commit what cannot be built from the rest that is there.